# Best way of building oauth into Jenkins Plugin

Tags: jenkins, oauth-2.0, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

I am working on a Jenkins plugin that uses the new Bitbucket Build Status API. The best way to access the API is using oauth.

What is the best way of building oauth into my Jenkins plugin? Should I use a oauth Java library or is there another Jenkins plugin I can depend my plugin on?

How would the process of "connecting" Jenkins and my plugin to the Bitbucket account (granting access and storing the tokens)?

Answer (score 0):

There is already a plugin for Jenkins that does extacly what you need I guess and use OAuth for authentication. Just take a look to the [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+Cloud+Build+Status+Notifier+Plugin).